# how to fetch this array using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, fetch

i have a multidimensional array. the array is returned by parsing xml using curl. when curl gave me the output i converted the output into array using $array = (array) simplexml_load_string($query);  and the $array is given below. Now i want to fetch this array using foreach loop and want everything from this array

```
Array
(
[Meta] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
      [Query] => php programming
      [ResultOffset] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

      [NumResults] => 25
      [TotalResults] => 36839
    )

[Slideshow] => Array
       (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [ID] => 1966058
                [Title] => title here
                [Description] => description here
                [Status] => 2
                [Username] =>usrname
                [URL] => url here
                [ThumbnailURL] => a url
                [ThumbnailSmallURL] => a url
                [Embed] => some embed code
    )
    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [ID] => 1966058
                [Title] => title here
                [Description] => description here
                [Status] => 2
                [Username] =>usrname
                [URL] => url here
                [ThumbnailURL] => a url
                [ThumbnailSmallURL] => a url
                [Embed] => some embed code
    )
```

and continue

Comment: What information you need to have acces in your loop ? For example: Status and Username.

Comment: i want everything from this array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve meta information without using foreach:

```
echo $array['Meta']->Query;
echo $array['Meta']->NumResults;
```

and so on...

To fetch slideshows:

```
foreach($array['Slideshow'] as $slideshow)
{
    echo $slideshow->ID;
    echo $slideshow->Title;
    //-- and so on...
}
```

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: echo $array['Meta']->Query;
                                                                     echo$array['Meta']->NumResults;                                                                                                         This is working fine but the another code in giving a warning that "Warning: Invalid argu" Help please

Comment: There can't be such warning if your `$array` is same as the one you posted in question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the ID and Titles of each SimpleXMLElement Object, try this:

```
<?php
forach ($array['Slideshow'] as $simpleXMLelem) {
  echo $simpleXMLelem->getId();
  echo $simpleXMLelem->getTitle();
}
```

Comment: @rajzana: Well you need to fill in `getArray()` with your own logic. Some effort required.