# Array having simplexml object.How to fetch it using foreach loop

Tags: php, curl, foreach, simplexml

i am having this code that is used for parsing a xml url and stores output in the $query variable.

```
 $url = 'http://www.slideshare.net/api/2/search_slideshows?api_key=GRCsS0fPo&
 ts=1320547556&hash=cf362f863d1f15e84c7a520804f7826731f958c4&q=electrical+engineering&
 page=4&download=0&items_per_page=25';

 echo $url;

 $ch=curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');

$query = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
$array = (array) simplexml_load_string($query);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
```

when i print this array using print_r($array) it gives me

```
Array
   (
   [Meta] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
     [Query] => php programming
      [ResultOffset] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

      [NumResults] => 25
      [TotalResults] => 36839
      )

      [Slideshow] => Array
     (
          [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [ID] => 1966058
            [Title] => title here
            [Description] => description here
            [Status] => 2
            [Username] =>usrname
            [URL] => url here
            [ThumbnailURL] => a url
            [ThumbnailSmallURL] => a url
               [Embed] => some embed code
    )
    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [ID] => 1966058
            [Title] => title here
            [Description] => description here
            [Status] => 2
            [Username] =>usrname
            [URL] => url here
            [ThumbnailURL] => a url
            [ThumbnailSmallURL] => a url
            [Embed] => some embed code
    )
```

now i want to fetch this array and use its every value. i want to all nodes values of this array. so how to fetch this array using foreach loop.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023179/how-to-fetch-this-array-using-foreach-loop

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use the SimpleXML XPath method rather than iterate over the array directly.

Comment: `foreach ($array->xpath('//Slideshow') as $slideShow) {
   echo $slideShow->Username;
}`

Comment: this is working fine but now an another problem has occured that the most of the time the array provided by curl becomes null. what is the problem. i am running the whole script on localhost.